# How to give a property and a method to one object that's with the new keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, properties

The "new Object" is not behaving the way I intended, when I assign value to the property I can't assign a method for it afterwards, I know how to work around but that's not the point of this question. In fact what I want to know is how the "new Object()" works, when assigned a property and well as methods.

```
var objeto = new Object();
objeto = "this is a property that I assigned"; //although if I give it a method like this
objeto.method = function(){alert(objeto)}; //the debugger would say that object.method is not a function
objeto.method(); //at this point method is not a function says the debugger
```

Can someone clarify this for me by any chance, because I'm stuck?

Comment: You are changing your Object to a String immediately after instantiating it...

Comment: I realized that, but what can I do perform what I intended. If possible?

Comment: I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `var objeto = new Object();`, just use `var objeto = {};`.

You are immediately changing your Object to a String with this line:

```
objeto = "this is a property that I assigned";
```

This should instead be:

```
objeto.property = "this is a property that I assigned";
```

Then replace your method with the following:

```
objeto.method = function(){alert(objeto.property)};
objeto.method();
```

The full code would read:

```
var objeto = {};
objeto.property = "this is a property that I assigned";
objeto.method = function(){alert(objeto.property)};
objeto.method();
```

Alternatively, you could do something like the following:

```
var objeto = {
    property: 'this is a property that I assigned',
    method: function(value) {
        alert(value);
    }
};

objeto.method(objeto.property);
```

Comment: Why not continue optimizing down to `var objeto = {property: "this is...", method: function () { ... }};`?

Comment: It would not be possible to access `objeto.property` inside `objeto.method` if it was instantiated that way unless OP passed this in as a function argument. I'll update my answer to include this scenario.